# XSL FO Docbook content left margin

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I'm using Docbook 5 (docbook-xsl-ns), generating PDF with Apache FOP and I would like to move all text to the left.
How can I do it?

Source XML is:

```
<section>
        <title>Usage</title>
        <programlisting>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=cz.csob.javor -DarchetypeArtifactId=javor-archetypes-subcomponent -DarchetypeVersion=X.Y.Z</programlisting>
        <para>During the subcomponent project generation you will be asked for the following properties:</para>
        <itemizedlist>
            <listitem>
                <para><emphasis>parent-component-id</emphasis> - ID of the parent component, should be the name of the directory the parent component project is placed in</para>
            </listitem>
            <listitem>...
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: most all appearances of things in docbook are controlled within the file "param.xsl" in the docbook/fo stylesheets. Examine it, find what you need to change and change it.

Comment: @Xdg - did you find solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paragraph indentation added by `body.start.indent` parameter.

You should set value to this parameter with measurement, because it's used in other XSLT templates for calculations. For example, next line will remove paragraph indentation at all:

```
<xsl:param name="body.start.indent">0pt</xsl:param>
```

All XSLT customization layer should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:import href="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/fo/docbook.xsl"/>
    <xsl:param name="body.start.indent">0pt</xsl:param>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Reference documentation for this topic](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintOutput.html#IndentingBodyText)

Also can be used other indentation options:

- `page.margin.inner` - left page margin
- `page.margin.outer` - right page margin

[image: Top and bottom margins (from documentation)]

For example next params will make this page layout [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozNDJ.png):

```
<xsl:param name="page.margin.inner">20mm</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="page.margin.outer">10mm</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="page.margin.top">12.5mm</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="page.margin.bottom">15mm</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="region.before.extent">10mm</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="region.after.extent">5mm</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="body.margin.top">15mm</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="body.margin.bottom">15mm</xsl:param>
```

[image: Resulting page layout]

Comment: Thanks @Viacheslav. That does a real nice job for the left margin of body text. What do we use for the right margin on body text? There is no `body.stop.indent`. (My problem seems to be, I don't know what things are called. `body.margin.left` and `body.margin.right` seem most intuitive, but they are wrong).

Comment: You can use this:

    <xsl:param name="page.margin.inner">20mm</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="page.margin.outer">10mm</xsl:param>